# java program for incrementing array at last

Tags: java

Write a java program with the following scenario.

A function which increments a string to create a new string.

If the string ends with a number, the number should be incremented by 1.
If the string doesn't end with a number, 1 should be added to the new string.
If the number has leading zeros, the amount of digits should be considered.

Comment: Can you add some test cases or examples?

Comment: please do add your approach

Answer (score 0):

You want to achieve something like this

1.If the last character is a number increment it. (Taken possibility of '9' as a last character so incrementing it to 10.)

2.If the last character is a not a number increment it.

```
String string = "StackOverflowError7";
  if(Character.isDigit(string.charAt(string.length()-1)))
      if(string.charAt(string.length()-1) != '9'){
          string = string.substring(0,string.length()-1) + (char)(string.charAt(string.length()-1)+1);
       } else {
           string = string.substring(0,string.length()-1) + "10";
       }
    else {
           string = string.substring(0,string.length()-1) + (char)(string.charAt(string.length()-1)+1);
     }
    System.out.println(string);//Final output
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for searching for an individual value, or a specific value that you want to find in a sequence:

```
static void methodOne() { 
        // initialize array 
        String[] array = { "one", "2", "three", "four" }; 
        // initialize value to search 
        String valueToSearch = "2"; 
        // initialize boolean variable 
        boolean isExists = false; 
        // iterate over array 
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
          // get the value at current array index 
          String arrayValue = array[i]; 
          // compare values 
          if (valueToSearch.equals(arrayValue)) { 
            isExists = true; 
            // if value is found, terminate the loop 
            break; 
          } 
        } 
        if (isExists) { 
          //add code
        } else { 
          //add code
      } 
    }
```

If you want to search strictly, then if it is a number, I recommend this:

```
private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");

public boolean isNumeric(String strNum) {
    if (strNum == null) {
        return false; 
    }
    return pattern.matcher(strNum).matches();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static final Pattern N = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(\\d+)");

static String increment(String s) {
    String r = N.matcher(s).replaceFirst(m ->
        String.format("%s%0" + m.group(2).length() + "d",
            m.group(1), Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)) + 1));
    return r.equals(s) ? s + "1" : r;
}

static void testIncrement(String s) {
    System.out.println(s + " -> " + increment(s));
}
```

and

```
testIncrement("abc0000");
testIncrement("abc0011");
testIncrement("abc0099");
testIncrement("abc9999");
testIncrement("abc012def8");
testIncrement("abc012def");
```

output:

```
abc0000 -> abc0001
abc0011 -> abc0012
abc0099 -> abc0100
abc9999 -> abc10000
abc012def8 -> abc012def9
abc012def -> abc012def1
```